# Dados dos vectores crear otro que contenga todos los valores de uno que no están en el otro

Tags: c, vectores, agregación

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio pero me encuentro con dos problemas.

- No sé como copiar a el vector c, los valores de a que no aparecen en b
- ¿Cómo sería el tamaño del vector c para imprimir? He intentado algo con bucles pero no consigo hallar la solución.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void combinar(int a[],int b[],int c[]);
void imprimir(int c[]);
int main() {
    int vec1[7];
    int vec2[7];
    int vec3[100];
    combinar(vec1,vec2,vec3);
    imprimir(vec3);
}
void combinar(int a[],int b[],int c[]){
    int i,aux=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        printf("Asigna valores al vector 1\n");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    }
    for (i = 0; i < 7 ; ++i) {
        printf("Asigna valores al vector 2\n");
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        c[i]=b[i];

    }
    for (i = 0;  i< 7; i++) {
        if(b[i] != a[i]){
            c[i]=a[i];

        }

    }

}

void imprimir(int c[]){

    for (int i = 0;  i< 14 ; i++) {
        printf("%d,",c[i]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El vector C debería tener el tamaño del vector A, ya que en el peor de los casos todos los elementos de A no se encuentran en B entonces tendrías como tamaño máximo posible de C el tamaño de A. Para eso defino una constante que indica el tamaño de los arrays.

Después en la función que llena los 3 arrays, devuelvo la cantidad de índices de C que fueron llenados, para pasar ese valor a otra función que recorrerá ese array C y lo imprimirá, ignorando los índices no llenados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define tam 5

int main(){

  int vec1[tam];
  int vec2[tam]; /* este puede tener otro tamaño, pero debes recordar cambiar los for() que recorren este array para que funcione */
  int vec3[tam];
      
  int fill(int vec1[], int vec2[], int vec3[]){ /* esta funcion devolvera la cantidad de elementos llenados en vec3 */
    int i, h;
    int flag;
    int pointer = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tam ; i++){
      printf("Asigna valores al vector 1\n");
      scanf("%d",&vec1[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < tam ; i++){
      printf("Asigna valores al vector 2\n");
      scanf("%d",&vec2[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){ /* buscamos todos los elementos de vec1 */ 
      flag = 0; /* comenzamos con flag = 0 */ 
      for(h = 0; h < tam; h++){ /* buscamos todos los elementos de vec2 */ 
        if(vec1[i]==vec2[h]) { /* si halla alguna coincidencia: */ 
          flag = 1; /* coloca flag en 1 */ 
          break; /* sale del for */ 
        }
      }
      if(flag==0) { /* si flag sigue siendo = 0; es porque no se encontro en vec2 el elemento evaluado en vec1, entonces se agrega ese elemento a vec3  */ 
        vec3[pointer] = vec1[i]; /* en la posicion de pointer, se asigna el valor no repetido de vec1 */
        pointer++; /* incrementamos pointer, comienza la siguiente iteracion esta vez evaluando el siguiente elemento de vec1 */
      }
    }
    return pointer; /* finalmente devolvemos pointer, esto nos ayudara mas adelante a imprimir vec3 
    esto es para guardar cuantos elementos fueron llenados y asi no imprimir indices vacios */
  }

  void printAll(int size){
    int i;
    if(size!=0){
      printf("\n Vector3: - ");
      for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%i",vec3[i]);
        printf(" - ");
      } 
    } else {
        printf("no se han encontrado elementos que esten en A pero no en B!");
    }
  }

  int size = fill(vec1, vec2, vec3); 
  printAll(size);
    
}
```

Cualquier cosa que no entiendas preguntas, estoy desempolvando mi C.

Answer (score 0):

Acostumbra a dividir el problema en partes más pequeñas para hacerlo más simple.

> No sé como copiar a el vector c, los valores de a que no aparecen en b.

Que un valor no aparezca, significa que no se encuentre.

Naturalmente puedes crear una función que busque un valor en un vector:

```
int encontrar(int vector[], int tamaño, int valor){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++){
        if (vector[i] == valor)
            return i;
    }

    // No encontrado
    return -1;
}
```

Y otra función que se encargue de hacer el paso más grande:

```
// Se asume que el tamaño de destino es mayor o igual al de origen
int copiarElementosExcepto(int origen[], int destino[], int tamanoOrigen, int excepto[], int tamanoExcepto) {
    int elementosCopiados = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanoOrigen; i++){
        int elemento = origen[i];
        int posicionEncontrado = encontrar(excepto, tamanoExcepto, elemento);
        if (posicionEncontrado == -1)
            destino[elementosCopiados++] = elemento;
    }

    return elementosCopiados;    
}
```

También es buena idea tener funciones más esenciales. Como estas:

```
void cargarValores(int vector[], int tamano){
    // Como los for tienen una sola instrucción puedes omitir las llaves
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
}

void imprimir(int vector[], int tamano){
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++)
        printf("%d, ", vector[i]);
}
```

El main quedaría así:

```
int main() {
    int vec1[7];
    int vec2[7];
    int vec3[100];

    printf("Asigna valores al vector 1\n");
    cargarValores(vec1, 7);
    imprimir(vec1, 7);

    printf("\nAsigna valores al vector 2\n");
    cargarValores(vec2, 7);
    imprimir(vec2, 7);
    printf("\n\n");

    int elementosCopiados = copiarElementosExcepto(vec1, vec3, 7, vec2, 7);
    imprimir(vec3, elementosCopiados);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVNNbxoxEL3vrxhRpQLtpsGQhMNmK1UV1/bWC@FgeQ0ZibVXtkGRqvx26i@WdTaQ@mJ7/Pze@M2Yte3tlrHj8QsKttvXHJ60qVF@e/meZSgMcMGkMIqqsdsdODNSrdYFuJ2hDRUyrA90J9XkbwZ2bKQCD0eoYFra6Sli7TrPI8oN3MA4cuIaqirSdOduKG72SgCWPvqW@enuDn7JLrlaZj3kLSmzt5A9ky1Stdzxhgsj9fKV8dZIn5tUuOXi9JSaa4NCpi/77SEhwsPVFBD5JhBe5HEnrZ9OupbaW/CJLUFoYE6Pzt6ICeO6TBCt1MhQimXnhcWeqxbzLtKMi454UibF@Iitso6mJTm5NXhsnq@degwnFYvFGVwp3aGr10FiDYyqLVV/XBdwfbHlrEnex4LuX6vE3WHD5Tmek9eMis14dFOPCvjaNd6k7PSxaRU2qK5J/0@Ld4qWThgvWYAVfafpGBqKYtxvIYshq0UscwzM3gfmKzKd2lDWF/mhcSto@ERcA91FPSDPYhQrnTrstApYxLPu9edwwv8sLirMrijMPlbohc8Cgebqd7rwqUPOzhrL6xcXdOfFkNaV43gkMIM53MMDPMIiczsyB3IP5AHII5BF9g8).