# Dados dos vectores a y b crear otro llamado c que sea la fusión de ambos (Que no aparezcan elementos repetidos)

Tags: array, c

en este programa lo tengo casi todo hecho ya que consigo al final el vector c que es una combinación de los vectores a y b de n dimensiones, el problema es que no se como eliminar un elemento repetido que aparezca en el vector a y b ej: vector a: 3,4,5 , vector b: 3,6, vector c: 3,4,5,6. Lo que me aparece al imprimir el vector c es 3,3,4,5,6 y yo quiero que el 3 no salga repetido, adjunto el código.Muchas gracias    ..................................................................

```
#include <stdio.h>
int tamano1,tamano2;
void ordenarysuma(int a[],int b[],int c[]);
int main() {
    int vec1[100];
    int vec2[100];
    int vec3[100];
    ordenarysuma(vec1,vec2,vec3);



}
void ordenarysuma(int a[],int b[],int c[]){
    int i,j,aux=0,aux2=0,aux3;
    printf("Introduce el tamano del vector1");
    scanf("%d",&tamano1);
    printf("Introduce el tamano del vector2");
    scanf("%d",&tamano2);
    for (i = 0; i <tamano1 ; i++) {

        printf("Dime los valores del vector1");
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <tamano2 ; i++) {

        printf("Dime los valores del vector2");
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <tamano1 ;i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j <tamano1 ; j++) {
            if(a[i]>a[j]){
                aux=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=aux;
            }
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i <tamano2 ;i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j <tamano2 ; j++) {
            if(b[i]>b[j]){
                aux2=b[i];
                b[i]=b[j];
                b[j]=aux2;
            }
        }

    }

    for (i = 0;  i<tamano1 ; i++) {
        c[i]=a[i];

    }
    for (i = tamano1; i <(tamano1+tamano2) ; i++) {
        c[i]=b[i-tamano1];

    }

    for (i =0 ; i <(tamano1+tamano2) ; i++) {
        for (j = 0;  j<(tamano1+tamano2) ; j++) {
            if(c[i]>c[j]){
                aux3=c[i];
                c[i]=c[j];
                c[j]=aux3;
            }
            if(a[i]==b[i]){
                c[i]=c[i+1];


            }

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < (tamano1+tamano2); i++) {
        printf("%d,",c[i]);

    }

    }
```

Comment: analizandolo me doy cuenta que debes validar mucho creo seria mas facil agregalos todos al arreglo C o agrega los del B al A y ya solo recorres el arreglo limpiando los duplicados con 2 ciclos anidados, en el primero tomas el valor a comparar y en el segundo lo recorres para ver si existe y con una variable de estado encontrado si es true lo borras o no lo agregas al array secundario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De manera similar a como te [respondí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/578349/169744) otra pregunta, divide el problema en partes más pequeñas.

Puedes crear una función `encontrar`:

```
int encontrar(int vector[], int tamaño, int valor, int desplazamiento = 0){
    for (int i = desplazamiento; i < tamaño; i++){
        if (vector[i] == valor)
            return i;
    }

    // No encontrado
    return -1;
}
```

Entonces la función que combina el resto del código se vería así:

```
int interseccion(int vector1[], int tamanoVector1, int vector2[], int tamanoVector2, int resultado[]) {
    int elementosCopiados = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanoVector1; i++){
        int elemento = vector1[i];
        int posicionEncontradoEnVector2 = encontrar(vector2, tamanoVector2, elemento);
        int posicionEncontradoEnResultado = encontrar(resultado, elementosCopiados, elemento);
        if (posicionEncontradoEnVector2 != -1 &&
            posicionEncontradoEnResultado == -1)
            resultado[elementosCopiados++] = elemento;
    }
    return elementosCopiados;    
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVTfb5swEH73X3FLtSgRdA1kWytRKk1TX/ewh76kPFjGyU4CG9lOVGnq357ZYAgEmsxRZPvufN999wNWVbc7xo7HGxSs2OccHrXJUX7580QICgNcMCmMomrhbgfOjFSbLAR3M7SkQjbnAy2kWv4lYNdWKqjNEVJYJXZ79Lb2HATeyi3cwsL7xAzS1Lvp9G4pbvZKACa19J3U290d/JJdcLkkPcvbKCHvTfT2z5XmjKEUPQLRkMFLI/RE6ks8ZRE3IsX1vjAWdJMtoeFSZ6rgJRdG6p@yQqvVNfkrCfHQo7z0/NknbdSYJQOTSmp01J67PDwLH6p9dSrdoQ3/jE0Lsbzu9ndLeuC4S0U4pj/t3hb8UtSfUls@mM8HHXAlHvfkvGXaCo2iCoLMMfDitqd63TN6kTila6iDxBwYVTuqXlybcv3hTNhS1uUO6f4tHTTBeCKCAE/Ra0bFdjH7nM9CmHeTsUw6fCwrhSWqS9D/M4MdonUnTA0ZggU9w3QeSopi0e90axNtotXKd6MXxWPR2otIH@iHxp2gzaRzDbTwmBC9iplvlWGWHV4I917XZeAkHvh/FR8ixBcQ4mmEnvgE0Li5OPmDL4@PtM5u3B7WE2jriTlyhTgeI4gghjV8hW/wnbiz3e3vHh7IPw).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me sale

Comment: @Edu si te sirvió marca la pregunta como respondida.